# How to add a UIView over a UIImageView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to make a feature where a user can see if someone is online or offline. If there are online there is a small green dot on the image, and red if offline. 
How can I build this? I have the circle image working but I am not sure how to add the green dot on it.
I am using Storyboards and UINibs. So I assumed I would need to make a UIView, not sure exactly how to place it.

I can build this in Swift UI, so is it possible to buildit in swiftUI, and add that image to a UICollectionView Cell?

Comment: just have one uiimageview and change the image depending on wether they're online or not. A green dot image for online and a red dot image for offline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with adding a UIImageView over that image, and used the SFSymbol "circle.fill"

I then used the ternary operator to determine the state.

Answer (score 0):

Just palce a label with a "." text in it, make the font as big as you would like it to be, apply constrains on it and then just change: myLabel.textColor = UIColor.green / myLalbel.textColor = UIColor.gray or whatever fits you, also note that you can apply centering of the text inside the label.